# How do I retrieve values from Html.TextBox MVC 2 asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a school project and I need some help.
I've created a form and I want to get the submitted values from it.
Is it possible to do this without using JavaScript?
And in that case, how do I do it?

Form:

```
<div id="secondRowInputBox">
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post))
        {%>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Id")%> <br />
            <%= Html.TextBox("CustomerCode") %><br />
            <%= Html.TextBox("Amount") %><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
        <%} %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done half the work, now in home controller make an actionresult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, string customerCode, int amount)
{
// work here.
}
```

form post method will call this method, as you have specified it in the begin form parameters.

It will be better if you use a model for passing values and use it in view for form elements

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelName modelinstance)
{
// work here.
}
```

Sample loginModel

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username:")]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

now if was using this login model in the form

then for the controller action, modelinstance is simply the object of model class

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginDetails)
{
// work here.
}
```

if you have a lot of variables in the form then having a model helps as you don't need to write for all the properties.

Comment: How do I use the modelinstance to get the values?

Answer (score 2):

Just create an `HttpPost` action in your controller accepting the form values as parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, string customerCode, int amount)
{
    // You can change the type of the parameters according to the input in the form.
    // Process data.    
}
```

You might want to look into [model binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx). This allows you to create strongly-typed views and saves you the trouble of creating actions with dozens of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Henk Mollema's answer is good. Here to say something more on it.

`Html.TextBox` will generate html like below one, there's a name attribute.

```
<input id="CustomerCode" name="CustomerCode" type="text">
```

When you submit the form, all the values of input fields can be get from Request.Form by name attribute as key `Request.Form["CustomerCode"]`, and ASP.NET MVC has done some magic for us, so it can simply go into the param of the action method.